# ProgressBar пока нет данных

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid

Изучаю `rxJava`, и вот я задался вопросом как можно показывать  `ProgressBar` если источник данных не излучил данные за 300 миллисекунд, и по мере наступления собственно убирать `Progressbar`.

Comment: Найдите решение без RX, потом прикрутите быстро. Ничем от любой асинхронной операции отличаться не будет по сути.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Я сделал с помощью двух `Observable` и одной логической переменной, но будоражит мысль что можно было все в одном `Observable` сделать.

Comment: @sakuraso13 вы используете MVP или MVVM?

Comment: @AlexLysun нет.

Answer (score -1):

можно так сделать

```
progerssBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
dataSource.getData()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doFinally(() -> { progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE) })
    .subscribe(data-> {
        .......
    }, throwable -> {
         .......
    });
```